# How do I get a QPushButton to move onMouseClick?

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 QPushButtons, one of which has no visual cue that it has been pressed and the other which moved the QPixmap down and to the right 1 or 2 pixels. I have no idea why the first isnt doing the same action as the second. How do I get it to do that too? (Is there some QSS that I've overridden that does this?)

Comment: are you using a style sheet ? if so post it along with the code

Answer (score 0):

Seems that one of your QPushButton is "default". Create correct styles for all necessary states (remove padding): http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton